# R and ggplot2: how do I connect the dots for a line chart and polar coordinates?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

[image: vis]

As my colleague points out, connecting the dots is something they teach in elemantary school.

Here is the data:

```
hour_timetable  mean_delayed_pass
0   6.074
1   6.512
2   7.632
3   9.393
4   8.759
5   4.600
6   6.040
7   5.575
8   5.680
9   6.315
10  6.895
11  7.852
12  6.832
13  6.961
14  6.322
15  5.954
16  5.579
17  5.540
18  5.142
19  5.579
20  6.139
21  6.501
22  6.140
23  6.061
```

and here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = test_vis, aes(x = factor(hour_timetable), y = mean_delayed_pass, group = 1)) + 
   ylim(0, NA) + 
   geom_point(color = 'purple', stat = 'identity') + 
   geom_line(color = 'purple') + 
   coord_polar(start = -0.12) # why offset?
```

Comment: If you keep `hour_timetable` as a numeric variable, instead of a factor, you will get a connected plot with no offset. Add `scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:22)` to get all the hour gridlines included.

Comment: Where did the 24th data point go?

Comment: Since `hour_timetable=0` is presumably also the "24th" hour, you need to add `24 6.074` as a new row to your data so that hour 23 won't be interpreted as the same time-point as 0. Sorry, forgot to mention that. There might be a more elegant way to deal with the periodic nature of the data, but at least it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `geom_polygon()` instead of `geom_line()`.  You can set an empty fill for the polygon with `geom_polygon(..., fill=NA)`.

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = test_vis, aes(x = factor(hour_timetable), y = mean_delayed_pass, group = 1)) + 
  ylim(0, NA) + 
  geom_point(color = 'purple', stat = 'identity') + 
  geom_polygon(color = 'purple', fill=NA) + 
  coord_polar(start = - pi * 1/24)
```

[image]

---

To put the zero point at the top of the plot, use `offset = - pi / 24`.